# extra white space between input elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

i am trying to remove the white space between two imput fields for all my form elements.
i decreased the height but after that the next label goes up
can you tell me how to remove it

http://jsfiddle.net/DA9gK/18/

```
<div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Company Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Contact Name</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Please separate you CSS and HTML in your fiddle. Also, you don't need to wrap all of your input fields in divs. You can just apply that class to the input field itself and eliminate quite a bit of unnecessary markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think this should solve your problem, I have answered it there. Thank you. [button alignment in form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347117/button-alignment-in-form-fields/14347496#14347496)</strike>

Damn! I apologize for the uncorrect fast answer, ok I have zeroed in on your problem, and the problem lies in the css file that you are importing viz. "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" and your elements are inheriting the style attribute from it, and your white space problem is exactly on 'line no 1945' where its explicitly defined

```
.form-horizontal .controls {
*display: inline-block;
*padding-left: 20px;
margin-left: 180px;
*margin-left: 0;
```

so either you have to manually override those or use the good old "!important" attribute.

PS: you have to edit the 'margin-left' attributes value to maybe 160px or something which you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone could help You by now. You have big mess here. Update jsfiddle with HTML and CSS windows. Btw - you're writing about padding or margin styles imo in labels. (margin-bottom:0)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the padding and margin on `label.control-label`. Remove the top padding or bottom margin. (I think removing the margin looks better.)

```
label.control-label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```